# How to use App ResourceDictionary and MergedDictionaries in other page - Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am having 2 Resource Dictionary `Dictionary1.xaml` and `Dictionary2.xaml` which having style for `TextBox` and `TextBlock`. I added both dictionary in `App.xaml` like this:

```
<Application
    x:Class="XAMLResources.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:XAMLResources">

    <Application.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush" Color="Yellow" />

        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="dict" Source="Dictionary1.xaml"/>

        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="mergeDictionary">
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary2.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

Now please help me to use those resource in page:

```
<Page
    x:Class="XAMLResources.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    >
    <StackPanel Margin="20,30,0,0">
        <TextBox Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

In this page please suggest me how to use those dictionary and merge dictionary for control `TextBox` in `MainPage.xaml`

***EDIT***
`Dictionary1.xaml` looks like:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:XAMLResources">

    <Style x:Key="eText" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe WP SemiLight"/>
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FAFAFA"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#D2D2D2"/>

    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Can I use this `eText` in UserControl or any page?

Comment: Waiting for some replies from you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's for example you have external resources defined in following manner in an external file.

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TitleBrush" Color="DarkViolet" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ContentBrush" Color="Black" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**EDIT**

According to you i have defined them in App.xaml

```
<Application
    x:Class="App2.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App2">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Now i'm using it in my normal xaml pages. The **TitleBrush** resource used in TextBlock is the same resource whose definition is actually present in the Dictionary1.xaml.

```
<Page
    x:Class="App2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App2"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock FontSize="20" Foreground="{StaticResource TitleBrush}" Text="Sample text" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

For further help you can refer [this link.](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Merged-Resource-Dictionaries-in-Silverlight-3.aspx)

Comment: This is fine, but I am having Resource Dictionary in App.xaml and want to access from UserControl or page, then please suggest way to use it.

Comment: From my understanding i feels that you were having a problem using merged dictionary resources in your normal xaml pages. I hope i have understood your problem.

Comment: I added xaml code for `Dictionary1.xaml`. Now this resource having style name `eText` can I use this style in any page or UserControl?

Comment: Also I find `x:Key` required to define `ResourceDictionary`, can I use it without `x:Key` value?

Comment: Yes you can use it in any page or user control using StaticResource attribute (provided you have first mentioned your resource file in your App.xaml)

Comment: x:key is used to Uniquely identify elements that are created and referenced in a XAML-defined dictionary. 

I don't think so you can add any new resource without using this keyword.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69437/discussion-between-ankush-madankar-and-akshay-soam).

Comment: Link at end of answer is dead - *"Not Found | The requested URL /items/Merged-Resource-Dictionaries-in-Silverlight-3.aspx was not found on this server."*.